# Screen Recorded Through Python Script is Too fast

Tags: python, numpy, pyautogui, screen-recording

I could record the screen, but whenever I play the video it is very fast. How can I solve this issue?

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np

resolution = (1920, 1080)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
filename = "Recording.avi"
fps = 60.0
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)
cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270)
while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    frame = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)    
    cv2.imshow('Live', frame)   
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
    time.sleep(1/30)
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 60 FPS requires each iteration to be 16 ms at most to keep up. You definitely won't achieve that when you waste 34 ms not doing anything (`time.sleep`), on top of acquiring, converting, compressing and displaying each FullHD frame.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to make the recorded video play at a normal speed. One possible solution is to reduce the number of frames per second (fps) that are being recorded. In your code, you are setting the fps value to 60.0, which is a very high value and may be causing the recorded video to play back too quickly. Try set fps to 25 or 30. Also you can try increasing the amount of time that the sleep() function is called, which will cause the loop to pause for a longer period of time between frames.

Comment: "try increasing the amount of time that the sleep() function is called" -- having too much time (in order to waste some more) is certainly not a problem OP has.

Answer (score 0):

Your video playback is set to 60.0fps.

You are probably capturing frames at a much slower pace.

let's say your "capture rate" is 20fps

When you combine the frames into a 60fps video, the video will effectively be sped up by a factor of 1:3

You have two solutions :

**1. Slow Down your playback fps:**

As @a5zima noted, if you slow down your playback framerate to match your capture frame rate, you video will playback at normal speed (1:1).

**2.Speed up your capture:**

You can also try to speed up the rate a which you capture the frames.
One way to achieve this is to use `mss` instead of `pyautogui`:

```py
import mss
import cv2
import numpy as np

resolution = (1920, 1080)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
filename = "Recording.avi"
fps = 60.0
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)
cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270)
while True:
    sct = mss.mss()
    img = sct.grab(mon)
    frame = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)    
    cv2.imshow('Live', frame)   
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
    time.sleep(1/30)
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Of course, there might be even faster methods to do the capture, so you may need to explore alternatives if this still doesn't satisfy your needs.